# Why do two different approaches using matrix algebra yield different results?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

I am solving a problem involving linear regression and I am finding that two different approaches to the matrix algebra is yielding different results.

In the second approach, I am merely simplifying the second component of the expression first. As you can see, the results are vastly different. Intuitively, I think the first approach is correct but I can't figure out what is wrong with the second approach to yield such a different answer.

Here, we assume $M_{x} = I -X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and $X'X$ is non-singular. I am hoping that your answer will help me better understand matrix algebra!

Approach 1:
$$
X'(M_{x})^{-1}X - X'(M_{x})^{-1}X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X) \\
X'(M_{x})^{-1}[I -X(X'X)^{-1}X']X \\
X'(M_{x})^{-1}M_{x}X \\
X'X
$$

Approach 2:
$$
X'(M_{x})^{-1}X - X'(M_{x})^{-1}X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X) \\
X'(M_{x})^{-1}X - X'(M_{x})^{-1}X \\
0
$$

Comment: Are you sure $M_x$ is invertible?

Answer (score 3):

As @Rahul noted in comment, $M_x$ is not invertible since 
$$
X'M_x=X'(I -X(X'X)^{-1}X') = X' - (X'X)(X'X)^{-1}X' = \mathbb 0
$$
where the result is zero rectangular matrix. It means that all rows of $M_x$ are linearly dependent and $M_x$ is singular.